# I am trying to get data from spotify api

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get data from spotify api but this error appears
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_1, _2, _3, _4}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

the data printed and after it printed this erroe appears

here is my code
`

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import Artist from '../components/Artist'
import SearchHeader from '../components/SearchHeader';
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import axios from 'axios';


const ArtistSearch = () => {
  const route = useRoute()
  let token = route.params.token
  console.log(token)

  const Artist = async () => {
    const resp = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=remaster%2520track%3ADoxy%2520artist%3AMiles%2520Davis&type=artist&market=ES&locale=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9&offset=5&limit=10', {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
    })
    console.log(resp)
  };


  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const DATA = [
    {
      image: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      name: 'First Item',
      number: 5
    },
    {
      image: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      name: 'First Item',
      number: 5
    },
    {
      image: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      name: 'First Item',
      number: 5
    },
  ];
  // Artist();
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={DATA}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Artist data={item} />}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      ListHeaderComponent={() => (
        <SearchHeader />
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default ArtistSearch

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
})
```

`

Comment: You might be hitting a situation where the async function you declared in the component scope called `Artist` is "declaring" over the `Artist` import which may be the component you're trying to render in the loop.

Comment: Concretely, you have an import `import Artist from '../components/Artist'`, but a few lines down, you've declared a function `const Artist = async () => {`. The async function is what React will try to "render".

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to summarise your problem.